# Joining the same table multiple times in ServiceStack AutoQuery

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to use ServiceStack's [Auto Query](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) feature against a table A which references another table B multiple times, but can't get it to work.

The root of this seems to be that AutoQuery generates joins without aliasing the joined tables, resulting in ambiguous columns. It fails both against SQL Server and Sqlite with similar errors. I haven't been able to find a way to work around this.

This is basically what I've done:

```
public class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Person))]
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Person))]
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Person Buyer { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Person Seller { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("/autoquery")]
public class AutoQueryRequest : QueryBase<Purchase, CustomPurchase>, IJoin<Purchase, Seller>, IJoin<Purchase, Buyer>
{ }
```

The full code can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/AVee/0cb0dc1912698fcc43df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrmLite (and by extension AutoQuery) doesn't support custom Aliases for Table JOIN's so you wont be able to query individual tables via AutoQuery.

Although the normal use-case of:

```
[Route("/purchase/query")]
public class QueryPurchase : QueryBase<Purchase>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

client.Get(new QueryPurchase { Id = 1 }).PrintDump();
```

Which will join and populate the [multiple self references](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#multiple-self-references):

```
{
        Offset: 0,
        Total: 1,
        Results:
        [
                {
                        Id: 1,
                        Description: Sonic Screwdriver,
                        SellerId: 2,
                        BuyerId: 1,
                        Buyer:
                        {
                                Id: 1,
                                Name: Rose Tyler
                        },
                        Seller:
                        {
                                Id: 2,
                                Name: Martha Jones
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

There's also a new `CustomJoin` API in OrmLite that will allow you to specify your own [Aliases on JOINS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28031793/85785).

### Using a Custom AutoQuery implementation

Since you can't query on the multiple self referenced tables, one way to do this is to use a Custom AutoQuery implementation where you can query the child table Id's in the custom AutoQuery implementation.

To do this we'll create an additional "backing" AutoQuery DTO `QueryPurchase` containing the properties that AutoQuery can handle whilst the `CustomPurchase` AutoQuery remains the public facing API that you want to expose for this service, e.g:

```
[Alias("Purchase")]
public class CustomPurchase : QueryBase<Purchase>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SellerName { get; set; }
    public string BuyerName { get; set; }
}

public class QueryPurchase : QueryBase<Purchase>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<int> BuyerIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> SellerIds { get; set; }
}
```

And in your custom AutoQuery implementation you can fetch the appropriate Buyer and Seller Id's and add them to the backing `QueryPurchase` Query, e.g:

```
public QueryResponse<Purchase> Any(CustomPurchase request)
{
    var qPurchase = request.ConvertTo<QueryPurchase>();

    if (request.BuyerName != null)
    {
        qPurchase.BuyerIds = Db.Column<int>(Db.From<Person>()
            .Where(x => x.Name == request.BuyerName)
            .Select(x => x.Id));
    }

    if (request.SellerName != null)
    {
        qPurchase.SellerIds = Db.Column<int>(Db.From<Person>()
            .Where(x => x.Name == request.SellerName)
            .Select(x => x.Id));
    }

    var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(qPurchase, Request.GetRequestParams());

    return AutoQuery.Execute(qPurchase, q);
}
```

AutoQuery understands Collection properties like `BuyerIds` and performs the appropriate query on `BuyerId`.

So now when calling this Service:

```
client.Get(new CustomPurchase { BuyerName = "Rose Tyler" }).PrintDump();
```

It will print the desired:

```
{
        Offset: 0,
        Total: 1,
        Results:
        [
                {
                        Id: 1,
                        Description: Sonic Screwdriver,
                        SellerId: 2,
                        BuyerId: 1,
                        Buyer:
                        {
                                Id: 1,
                                Name: Rose Tyler
                        },
                        Seller:
                        {
                                Id: 2,
                                Name: Martha Jones
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

### Appending Custom Conditions

In similar spirit another way to approach this would be to add customized conditions to the AutoQuery itself, for this we no longer need the `BuyerIds` or `SellerIds` properties, e.g:

```
public class QueryPurchase : QueryBase<Purchase>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The `QueryPurchase` DTO holds the `Purchase` table properties that AutoQuery can handle minus the `SellerName` and `BuyerName` which needs to be special-cased, e.g:

```
public QueryResponse<Purchase> Any(CustomPurchase request)
{
    //Copy only the properties that AutoQuery can handle
    var qPurchase = request.ConvertTo<QueryPurchase>();
    var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(qPurchase, Request.GetRequestParams());

    //Add Custom SQL Conditions for each Custom Query
    if (request.BuyerName != null)
        q.UnsafeWhere("BuyerId IN (SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE Name = {0})", 
            request.BuyerName);

    if (request.SellerName != null)
        q.UnsafeWhere("SellerId IN (SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE Name = {0})", 
            request.SellerName);

    return AutoQuery.Execute(qPurchase, q);
}
```

This is similar to the above custom AutoQuery implementation except it gets added to the single AutoQuery query.

Likewise calling this Service:

`csharp
client.Get(new CustomPurchase { BuyerName = "Rose Tyler" }).PrintDump();`

Also prints the desired:

```
{
        Offset: 0,
        Total: 1,
        Results:
        [
                {
                        Id: 1,
                        Description: Sonic Screwdriver,
                        SellerId: 2,
                        BuyerId: 1,
                        Buyer:
                        {
                                Id: 1,
                                Name: Rose Tyler
                        },
                        Seller:
                        {
                                Id: 2,
                                Name: Martha Jones
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

To support this there's a new `UnsafeWhere` API's to OrmLite's `SqlExpression` in order to be able to add unverified raw SQL like the sub SELECT added above. The parameters still get escaped which will prevent any SQL Injections. This change is available from **v4.0.37+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).